# Raspberry Pi Water Level Sensor doesn't work

Tags: gpio, python, pi-2, sensor, connection

I got a question. I'm trying to make a water level sensor to check the water level with Raspberry Pi and a water level sensor using this tutorial. https://kookye.com/2017/06/01/design-a-water-level-detector-through-a-raspberry-pi-board-and-water-level-sensor/

I followed everything on this tutorial.

The issue I'm facing is that when I start the program and insert water level sensor inside the water the program should display water level info on display but the moment I insert water level sensor inside the water, the program stops displaying info, when I remove water level sensor from the water it starts displaying info. The weird thing that this info displayed on the display when I remove the water level sensor I think it shows what level it was inserted inside the water.

The code I'm using is also from this tutorial, I also found some similar tutorial with the same code. So I think code is correct, just something wrong with my connection, or maybe my water level sensor is broken.

I hope you understand my question I someone will help me with it!

Thank you, everyone, a lot!

I add some photos of my connections.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: you did not ask an actual question ... you described the problem and you are making an assumption that everyone would ask the same question

Comment: [Watch this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udmJyncDvw0), then find another tutorial.

Comment: Seamus - thank you for this video is really helpfull. I'm probably going to find another tutorial with different sensor.